# Square block matrix, with Hermitian, non-negative definite blocks, prove that the matrix is also non-negative definite,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Consider the square block matrix

$$S=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        R & RQ^* \\
        QR & QRQ^* \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $R$ is a Hermitian, non-negative definite square matrix and $Q$ and $Q^*$ are square Hermitian conjugate matrices.  Prove that $S$ is also non-negative definite.

Edit:  My first thoughts would be to try and do a similarity transformation to see whether I can diagonalize S, or put S in some form where I can then observe its eigenvalues, which are invariant under a similarity transform.  Would I be on the right track...?  I need to show the eigenvalues are non-negative..

Comment: You could try to factor $S$ in $VV^{*}$, or you could also try straightforwardly the definition $x^{T}Sx \ge 0$, $\forall x$. These are also possible points of attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the similarity transform idea. The blocks on the bottom row have $Q$ on the left and the blocks on the right column have $Q^*$ on the right. Hence, we can write $S$ as:

$$S = \begin{bmatrix}R & RQ^* \\ QR & QRQ^*\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ 0 & Q\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R & R \\ R & R\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ 0 & Q^*\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, $S = \begin{bmatrix}R & RQ^* \\ QR & QRQ^*\end{bmatrix}$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}R & R \\ R & R\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, can you show that $\begin{bmatrix}x^* & y^*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R & R \\ R & R\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} \ge 0$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$?

Try multiplying that product out and factoring it.

EDIT: Showing that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x^* & y^*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}R & RQ^* \\ QR & QRQ^*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = (x^*+y^*Q)R(x+Q^*y) \ge 0$$

for all $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is pretty easy as well, so I guess the similarity transform wasn't really needed.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty carrying the block multiplication, @JimmyK4542.  Can you elaborate just a bit on how to do it?  I'm pretty sure that the way I'm doing it is way too wordy and probably incorrect...

Comment: ...for example, is your [x,y] *one* nx1 vector or two vectors that add up to size nx1? (Assuming S is of size nxn)

Comment: If $R$ and $Q$ are $n \times n$ matrices, then $S$ is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix. So, we need to show that $v^*Sv \ge 0$ for all $2n \times 1$ vectors $v$. All I did was break up $v$ into two $n \times 1$ vectors $x$ and $y$.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I started with.  but then i started the multiplication of $[x^* y^*]$ with S, but I'm going through *every* column of S.  is there a shorter way to do this? haha...might just be a rule that I am missing...(I know I'm supposed to end up with a 1x2n matrix to multiply against the column vector [x,y]...)

Comment: So I'm breaking out R into its individual entries, R_11, R_21 ...etc...

Comment: There is no need to break $R$ into individual entries. Block matrix multiplication works like regular matrix multiplication. When multiplying $\begin{bmatrix}x^* & y^*\end{bmatrix}$ by $S$, the result will be $\begin{bmatrix}x^*R+y^*QR & x^*RQ^*+y^*QRQ^*\end{bmatrix}$. This is what you would get if $x,y,R,Q$ were all scalars which weren't allowed to commute.

Comment: Ah, ok got it.  I'll do this over now.  Thanks so much for your time!  Have a great night, @JimmyK4542 :)

Comment: I'm just finishing up this problem, @JimmyK4542, and am stuck on one last thing:  I know you said to treat the components as non-commuting scalars.  But with this in mind, it's a little tricky so far, to factor out the R correctly.  Is factoring allowed?  I'm pretty sure you must have done some factorization, but wouldn't that amount to *some* commuting of scalars (matrices)? Maybe not, but I just wanted to confirm with you. Perhaps you're using the associativity rule for matrices.  Thanks...

Comment: That may have been a bad way to explain how block matrix multiplication works. Anyway, matrix multiplication is associative but NOT commutative. Matrix addition is both associative and commutative. When you finish the block multiplication, you get $x^*Rx+y^*QRx+x^*RQ^*y+y^*QRQ^*y$ which can be rearranged as $x^*Rx+x^*RQ^*y+y^*QRx+y^*QRQ^*y$, which then factors as $x^*R(x+Q^*y)+y^*QR(x+Q^*y) = (x^*+y^*Q)R(x+Q^*y)$. Note that when you expand the factored result, you get all the original terms provided you don't change the order in which terms are multiplied.

Comment: Ah, ok - I just got it :)  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{R}$ is PSD by assumption. Hence, there exists $\mathbf{V}$ such that
$$
\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*}.
$$
To show that $\mathbf{S}$ is also PSD, it suffices to show that there exists a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^{*}$.

For 
$$
\mathbf{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{V}\\
\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{V}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
we have
$$
\mathbf{B}
\mathbf{B}^{*}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{V}\\
\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{V}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{V}^{*}&
\mathbf{V}^{*}\mathbf{Q}^{*}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*}& \mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*}\mathbf{Q}^{*}\\
\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*} & \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*}\mathbf{Q}^{*}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{R}& \mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q}^{*}\\
\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}& \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{Q}^{*}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\mathbf{S}.
$$